# Does C# have an equivalent of Delphi's message keyword?

Tags: c#, delphi, windows-messages

In delphi, I can create my own message like this,

```
const MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER+100;
procedure MyMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message MY_MESSAGE;

procedure TForm1.MyMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
....
end;
```

bu in c# I can do that like this

```
public static uint ms;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{       
 if(m.Msg == ms) 
    MessageBox.Show("example");
    else
    base.WndProc(ref m);        
}

void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,ms,IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

but I don't want to override WndProc(), I want to create my own MyMessage() function, and when I post message it will run.

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's a special feature of Delphi of which there is no analogue in C#. In C# you need to override `WndProc()`.

Answer (score 9):

Something that looks *very* similar can be done using `.NET` reflection and custom attributes. I think performance would be OK for production use, but not worth it since this still requires overriding `WndProc` to call the custom dispatcher, and once the `WndProc` is put into place, it takes one line of code to call the custom dispatcher OR 3 lines of code to write a proper `switch` statement. If the code is called from a "base" class you then inherit from it might be worth it.

#### Just in case you were wondering, I'm doing this because I'm lerarning C# + .NET and was curious what could be done.

Here's how the code would look like, once the "plumbing" is done:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
    
    // This is the Delphi-lookalike declaration for the WM_MOUSEMOVE handler.
    // I'd say it looks very much "alike!"
    [WinMessageHandler(WM_MOUSEMOVE)]
    public bool UnHandler(ref Message X)
    {
        this.Text = "Movement";
        return false;
    }

    // While simple, this is unfortunately a deal-breaker. If you need to go through the
    // trouble of writing this stub WndProc, might as well write a proper switch statement
    // and call the handler directly.
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (!WinMessageDispatcher.Dispatch(this, ref m)) base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

And here's the "plumbing". A *lot* more code that implements the code to identify all windows message handler routines (based on custom attribute), and cache all those results using a couple of dictionaries (so the heavy-lifting only needs to be done once).

```
// Custom attribute to set message ID
class WinMessageHandler : System.Attribute
{
    public int Msg;
    public WinMessageHandler(int Msg) { this.Msg = Msg; }
}    

class WinMessageDispatcher
{
    
    // This is cached for the life of the application, it holds the required per-type
    // dispatching information.
    private class WinMessageDispatcher_PerType
    {
        private Dictionary<int, System.Reflection.MethodInfo> dict;

        // generic handler
        public bool HandleMessage(object OnInstance, ref Message msg)
        {
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo method;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(msg.Msg, out method))
            {
                // Set up the call
                object[] p = new object[1];
                p[0] = msg;
                return (bool)method.Invoke(OnInstance, p);
                msg = p[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Constructor, initializes the "dict"
        public WinMessageDispatcher_PerType(Type t)
        {
            dict = new Dictionary<int, System.Reflection.MethodInfo>();
            foreach (var method in t.GetMethods())
            {
                var attribs = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WinMessageHandler), true);
                if (attribs.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Check return type
                    if (method.ReturnParameter.ParameterType != typeof(bool)) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} doesn't return bool", method.Name));

                    // Check method parameters
                    var param = method.GetParameters();
                    if (param.Length != 1) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} doesn't take 1 parameter", method.Name));
                    // Ooops! How do I check the TYPE of the "ref" parameter?
                    if (!param[0].ParameterType.IsByRef) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} doesn't take a ref parameter of type System.Windows.Forms.Message but a parameter of type {1}", method.Name, param[0].ParameterType.ToString()));

                    // Add the method to the dictionary
                    dict.Add(((WinMessageHandler)attribs[0]).Msg, method);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Dictionary to link "Types" to per-type cached implementations
    private static Dictionary<Type, WinMessageDispatcher_PerType> dict;

    // Static type initializer
    static WinMessageDispatcher()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<Type, WinMessageDispatcher_PerType>();
    }

    // Message dispatcher
    public static bool Dispatch(object ObjInstance, ref Message msg)
    {
        if (ObjInstance == null) return false;
        else
        {
            WinMessageDispatcher_PerType PerType;
            lock (dict)
            {
                if (!dict.TryGetValue(ObjInstance.GetType(), out PerType))
                {
                    PerType = new WinMessageDispatcher_PerType(ObjInstance.GetType());
                    dict.Add(ObjInstance.GetType(), PerType);
                }
            }
            return PerType.HandleMessage(ObjInstance, ref msg);
        }
    }
    
}
```